# How to enable LDAP auth for SFTP logins only

Tags: ldap, sftp, pam

I currently use ActiveDirectory for authentication on my Ubuntu 10.04 servers using a tool called Centrify Express.  Centrify has a custom .so file that is configured in /etc/pam.d/common-auth.

I'd like to do normal LDAP authentication (bypassing centrify) for just SFTP users (not SSH logins).  How would I configure /etc/pam.d/sshd to try LDAP authentication for SFTP logins, but not SSH logins?  The idea is that my SFTP OU would allow users to download, and upload files, but they wouldn't be able to get a shell.

Comment: What is it about Centrify that makes plain LDAP a more suitable alternative for `sftp` users?

Comment: Centrify Express (the free version) doesn't allow us to control the UID, and GID of users/groups.  When a user connects, they are given a random UID near the top of the range.  This makes managing permissions across servers difficult.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking to provide *only* `sftp` service (that is, no interactive logins via `ssh`).

You can force connections to use the `sftp` service by adding this to your `sshd_config` file:

```
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

This is documented in the `sshd_config` man page:

```
ForceCommand
  Forces the execution of the command specified by ForceCommand, ignoring any
  command supplied by the client and ~/.ssh/rc if present.  The command is
  invoked by using the user’s login shell with the -c option.  This applies to
  shell, command, or subsys- tem execution.  It is most useful inside a Match
  block.  The command originally supplied by the client is available in the
  SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND environment variable.  Specifying a command of
  “internal-sftp” will force the use of an in-process sftp server that requires
  no support files when used with ChrootDirectory.
```

You can modify `/etc/pam.d/sshd` to configure sshd to use the normal `pam_ldap` module rather than the `pam` module provided by Centrify.

With these configuration changes in place, `sftp` connections will use normal `LDAP` authentication, and interactive shells will not be available.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you could limit it in pam, but if you make all the users you want to constrict members of one group, you can have ssh restrict what those users could do via match group blah.